# Are there any artifically intelligent Starfleet ships?

Tags: star-trek, artificial-intelligence

We know the computer on Starfleet ships has very advanced AI to interact with the crew, but also it can produce very complex simulations in the holodeck with person-to-AI interaction.

So did Starfleet ever design a fully AI vessel for research / combat?

(I would prefer canon-only answers.)